# When was Deadpool first described as "The Merc with a Mouth" in comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, deadpool

Specifically, I would like to know whether it was before or after the movie in which he did not have a mouth.

Comment: Presumably the movie you’re referring to is _X-Men Origins: Wolverine_?

Comment: Oh, no don't mention this abominable motion picture!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first reference I can find is from [*Deadpool: Sins of the Past Vol 1* Issue 1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Deadpool:_Sins_of_the_Past_Vol_1_1) that was released August 1994. Incidentally this is also the reference to the nickname from the Fandom page for Wade. The name appears as a caption not said by a character as far as I can tell.

[image: Page from the above comic showing a close up of Wade’s disfigured face as a girl runs out the door horrified]